# How to create Table in the root schema

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a project. I have main user - Admin. And I have User1. I granted multiple permissions to the user1. After the reading, I realize that in order to create a table in root schema I need to CREATE ANY TABLE grant. However, how would I specify that I want to place that table specifically to Admin(root) schema? 
Also, under the User1 I try to grant permissions to the new Role(which I created under User1) and the oracle SQl developer gives me an error that I have insufficient privileges(even though I granted create role permission). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using ```create table admin.table_name``` when you are creating the table? This should specify the table to be in the root schema but if you have logged in as User1 then you should have the same privileges as that of the Admin(root) user to create the table in root schema.

Comment: There is no such concept of a "root" schema in Oracle. There are ordinary user schemas and there are system schemas (but you would never create objects in the system schemas).